# An error in my code to upload photos {"error":{"message":"(#240) The target_id references an inactive user","type":"OAuthException","code":240}}

Tags: facebook

Please help. The code to upload photos to an album by. After changing the code was not working, reports error {"error": {"message": "(# 240) The references target_id an inactive user", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 240}} I tried everything I have nothing but think. I'm looking professional and support here. Thank you for every answer.

```
$app_id = "xxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxx";
$post_login_url = "http://redirectpage";
$album_id = "1";
$photo_url = "http://myimg.com";
$photo_caption = "xxxxxxxxx";
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
if (!$code){ 
 $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"`enter code here`
  . "client_id=" .  $app_id
  . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
  .  "&scope=publish_stream";
echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
  . "'</script>");
} else {
$token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
  . "client_id=" . $app_id
  . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
  . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
  . "&code=" . $code;
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$access_token = $params['access_token'];


$graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/" 
  . $album_id . "/photos?"
  . "url=" . urlencode($photo_url)
  . "&message=" . urlencode($photo_caption)
  . "&method=POST"
  . "&access_token=" .$access_token;

echo '<html><body>';
echo file_get_contents($graph_url);
echo '</body></html>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the current user has authorized the application (installed it)?

Also, this bug report: [Photo upload via PHP SDK OpenGraph](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325292497524672/?browse=search_4f86f2f707ce21d13657399) is among the first results for gooling "The references target_id an inactive user".

I'm not much of a php expert, but this does not seem like the correct way to POST an image, maybe you should use the method shown in the code in that bug report.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Code but it worked, but facebook did some changes. Then stop the application working.